# AS3 add if statement to switch?

Tags: if-statement, actionscript-3, switch-statement

I'm creating a game in AS3 and currently working on the menu. Don't hate I'm very new to this.

I want this to happen when the case: singlePlayerX. This part starts a new single player game when you press 1 on the keyboard. The problem here is I'm not sure where to insert this part or if that's even possible.

```
if (Input.keyboard.justPressed(this.evertron_keys.PLAYER_BUTTON_1)) {
                Session.application.displayState = new Game();
```

This is the switch I'm currently working with:

```
if (Input.keyboard.justPressed(this.evertron_keys.PLAYER_DOWN)) {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < this.add_layer.numChildren; i++) {
                    switch (this.add_layer.getChildAt(i)) {

                        case this.singlePlayerX:
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.singlePlayerX);
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.singlePlayer);
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.multiPlayerX);             
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.multiPlayer);
                            break;

                        case this.multiPlayerX:
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.multiPlayerX);              
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.multiPlayer);
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.highScoreX);               
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.highScore);
                            break;

                        case this.highScoreX:
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.highScoreX);                
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.highScore);
                            this.add_layer.addChild(this.singlePlayerX);                
                            this.add_layer.removeChild(this.singlePlayer);
                            break;
                    }

                }

            }
```

What this part does is changes what is on the screen when you press button down. So basically what I want is when you press 1 on when case this.singlePlayerX = new Game,
when case this.multiPlayerX = new Multiplayer, and so on.
I have tried putting the new Game if statement in the switch statement but nothing happens when I press 1.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: Because your **switch** clause is processed when you press "DOWN" button, which obviously cannot happen at the same time as you press that "1" button. I don't know what your project hierarchy is, but common sense is that both **if (Input...** statements are the same level statements and should reside one next to the other.

Comment: Your answer put me on the right path and solved my problem, thank you so much! I just created another if-statement for (Input.keyboard.justPressed(this.evertron_keys.PLAYER_BUTTON_1). I have no idea why that didn't cross my mind earlier.

Comment: Glad it helped.